# Using C# to Search OCR (searchable) PDF

Tags: pdf, ocr

I need to extract the text from a PDF that has already been transformed using a OCR program. Do I use a normal PDFReader to get the text or does an OCR transformed PDF require special handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how it has been transformed.  Many OCR apps put the text under the image in some way.  Some do this by laying the text down first the placing the image on top.  Some place the image on the bottom then lay the text on top using the "don't mark" transfer mode.

I mention this because I can't predict how any particular text extraction tool will respond to transparent text.  In theory, it should just give you the text (this is what Acrobat does).  Whether this happens in reality across all text extraction tools is anyone's guess.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was the closest to what I was asking (which I clearly didn't ask properly). A OCR transformed PDF is no different from a non-OCR PDF as far as the PDF format goes. The OCR process just scans the images and adds the text to the PDF. I used Aspose to extract text and I wanted to make sure nothing bad would happen if a non-OCR PDF was given to my program.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of commercial SDK's for handling pdf files. http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/activex/ Here's foxit's.

Comment: My question is whether or not PDFs transformed using some OCR software is handled any different from a normal PDF. Or is an OCR transformed PDF just a PDF with more text instead of images. I don't know a whole lot about the PDF structure.